# Get the index while iterating on a multi-index dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

While iterrating over the `shop_id`, I am trying to get the `shop_id` values in a multi-index DataFrame:

```
                         total_sales
shop_id date_block_num              
0       0               3.034985e+09
        1               3.547803e+09
```

So I tried:

```
for i, shop_sales in monthly_change.groupby(level=0):
    print(shop_sales['shop_id'])
```

But it returned a key error.

I also tried `shop_sales.index` but I don't understand how I could use the results

```
MultiIndex([(0, 0),
            (0, 1)],
           names=['shop_id', 'date_block_num'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work because you try to get the column **shop_id**, but after the groupby, it has become an index, so this won't provoke an error :

```py
for i, shop_sales in monthly_change.groupby(level=0):
    print(shop_sales.reset_index()['shop_id'])
```

But I don't really understand what you're trying to do...
This maybe ?

```py
for shop in monthly_change.index.get_level_values(0):
    print(monthly_change.loc[shop])
```

Or even a more simple :

```py
monthly_change.loc[0]
```

To get shop_id == 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) if need first or second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
for i, shop_sales in monthly_change.groupby(level=0):
    #grouping by first level, so get scalar 
    print(i)
    #if need first level of MultiIndex
    print (monthly_change.index.get_level_values('shop_id'))
    
    #if need second level of MultiIndex
    print (monthly_change.index.get_level_values('date_block_num'))
    
0
Int64Index([0, 0], dtype='int64', name='shop_id')
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64', name='date_block_num')
```